# nested array conversion from PHP to C#

Tags: c#, php, arrays, nested

I have PHP code

```php
$records = array(
    array('myobjecttype' => array('field1' => 'value', 'field2' => 'value')),
    array('myotherobjecttype' => array('field1' => 'value', 'field2' => 'value'))
);
```

I am working on converting php code to C#. Above php code is used later to loop through and create xml where each array is Node in xml.

I need similar data structure in c# which can do the same task. Kindly guide me.

Pavan

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code conversion service. See the [FAQ] and [Ask].

Comment: I don't need code conversion service. I need help in identifying right data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a proper class with properties and create a list of them?

```
public class Record
{
    public string Field1{get;set;}
    public string Field2{get;set;}
}
```

And then in your method you do the following:

```
var recordA = new Record{Field1 = "Value 1", Field2 = "Value 2"};
var recordB = new Record{Field1 = "Value 1", Field2 = "Value 2"};

var records = new List<Record>{recordA, recordB};
```

**UPDATE**

You obviously want to define the Record properties with a proper names like *Title*, *ReleaseDate* etc. and give them types like int, DateTime etc.

Comment: Hi James,Each array can be different on every call. There is no standard definition(decided by user) hence didn't prefer class.Thanks

Comment: So you don't know what structure you are having? How do you get the data in to your c# application?

Comment: It will generally be string or integer.I need a data structure to hold these data like above array.I looked at hash table,dictionary also Jagged array.

Comment: But you know all the different object types? Where do you get your list of objects from?

Comment: OK, I give up, the requirements are not clear to me. Sorry, but you probably should rephrase your question and try again...